# Reviewing answer with no question

Tags: bug, review

In the late answers review queue, I was asked to review an [answer with no question](https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/161600).

Answer:

> Be sure that you have exclusive IP address on this subscription.

Question:

> question not found

Without knowing what the question is, I really can't figure out if this is an appropriate answer or not. Would it be correct to assume this is a bug in the review system?

After flagging the answer for moderator attention the question showed up, but if I look at the review in an incognito window, the question is still missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must have been an audit as I deleted the Answer a month ago. Unfortunately moderator actions are used as the basis for some of the audits; even when the whole question get filed in the circular bin.